# Passing a encoded string through a decoder - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been given the string '3950716622786379081707106990440289649627095539059008641465751322761465613969175568136135330180128764700469690212693880571268104774', which has been encoded.

Also have been given a Python file which contains the function:

```
def bin2utf(bin_string):
    utf_string = bin(bin_string)[2:]
    utf_string = ('%x' % int(utf_string, 2)).decode('hex').decode('utf-8')
    return utf_string
```

How would I go about passing the encoded string through this function in order to decode it? So far everything I have tried has not worked.

My last effort was:

```
from decoder import bin2utf

bin_string = ('3950716622786379081707106990440289649627095539059008641465751322761465613969175568136135330180128764700469690212693880571268104774')
bin2utf(int(bin_string))
```

Am assuming I've missed something, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's not supposed to be a string after all...

Comment: It looks like you should just pass `int(yourString)` into the function

Comment: Edit shows my last effort, I know it's wrong I just can't work out why

Comment: @Quarismo, It works! You just need to *actually print the result!* --> `print bin2utf(int(bin_string))` --> `[14] Well done on completing your mission 004.` :) You *did* `return utf_string` from the function, but you haven't printed it out

Comment: @downshift, yeah it works, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Quarismo, cool! Glad you got it working! Cheers! :)